# Locking while front-end waits on response from backend

Tags: reactjs, state

End users in our react application have the ability to make payments to loans via a pop up. The initial problem that we encountered is that users could click the pay button twice (or heaven forbid more than twice) and this would create multiple payments throwing our accounting into disarray. We thus implemented a sort of lock state that, when triggered to true, shows a loading gif displayed in a div with a simple tweak of the z-index. The state is passed down to the pop up from 2 components above. Every now and then I get an error message displaying that there is a possible memory leak. I assume this has something to do with my fix.

I'm just wondering, is there best practice on how to handle this sort of "locking" situation with react while waiting on some other external system to respond? I've tried to do this via the front-end but I'm not 100% convinced that it's the best and/or only solution.

If you need some code to better illustrate the scenario then let me know and I'll work on adding some examples.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: How about setting the pay button to disabled after it's clicked?

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of ways of doing this.  You could even had multiple layers to the process.  On top of layering the page using a `z-indexed` loading screen, you could also disable the button depending on some form of state change.

Also, the memory leak could be from you not disposing everything after the life cycle of a particular hook ends.  I would suggest you look at using `useEffect` as a starting point.  There's a good chance that either your modal or loading indicator is causing this.  Often times, this can be fixed by adding a dependency array to `useEffect`.  Obviously, I am making a lot of assumptions here.

Comment: Hey AttemptedMastery, thanks for your response! I think the right answer is to disable the button when processing the request. Although we had the set a layer on top of the pop up form (thus mitigating any clicks) we hadn't thought about the enter button. Enabled the disabled tag allows us to kill 2 birds with 1 stone. I'll have a look into the useEffect issue. Thanks for the heads up!